# Trying to loop and display a JSON file with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I have a JSON file that has an array inside. I want to loop inside each element of the JSON and display it. I can succesfully do it but I want when using the foreach loop refer to the field like this: `$value["pessoa_id"];`

When I'm doing like this I get it to display but after displaying it gets a message: "Notice: Undefined index: nome", like it was trying to access it again.

This is the JSON file:

```
{"Clientes": {
      "Pessoa": [
        {"pessoa_id" : 1,  "nome": "INDUSTRIAL JAVARI LTDA",  "endereco": "ENGENHO SANTA TERESA"},
        {"pessoa_id" : 2,  "nome": "AGROISA-AGRO IND. TRAVESSIA S/A",  "endereco": "FAZENDA TRAVESSIA S/N"}
      ],
      "Clientes": [
        {"cliente_id" : 1,  "loja" : 1,  "cliente" : 1,  "tpcli": "J",  "pontoref": ""},
        {"cliente_id" : 2,  "loja" : 1,  "cliente" : 2,  "tpcli": "J",  "pontoref": ""}
      ]
    }
  }
```

And the php code:

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents("clitest.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
foreach ($json as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $key => $val){
      foreach ($val as $key => $v){
          echo $v["nome"] . " " . $v["endereco"];
          echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to in one foreach see if it's a "Pessoa" or "Clientes" and loop throught it by getting the fields by the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also iterate over the 2nd array `Clientes`. You could access the array directly and only iterate over that data:

```php
$jsondata = file_get_contents("clitest.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$pessoa = $json["Clientes"]["Pessoa"];
foreach ($pessoa as $key => $value){
  echo $value["nome"] . " " . $value["endereco"];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

**Update:**

If you need/want to loop over the whole data-set like you did in your question, you can check if you are in the correct element of the object and only than iterate and output the data.

```php
$jsondata = file_get_contents("clitest.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
foreach ($json as $key1 => $value){
  if ($key1 == "Clientes") {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $val){
      if ($key2 == "Pessoa") {
        foreach ($val as $key3 => $v){
          echo $v["nome"] . " " . $v["endereco"];
          echo "<br>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about the things from Clientes? I wanna be able to see if is on Pessoas or Clientes and get their ID and fields.

Comment: I have added another example that uses your loops from the question, and checks if the key is equal to a specific name and only iterates then over the content. You can modify that to your own needs.